# Saving a todo list in Emacs org-mode removes all plain text?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I started to use the Emacs org-mode for my todo lists.
However, when I save my file all plain text is removed, how do I prevent this from happening?

e.g.

file todo.org:

> - thing 1
> - thing 2
>     Some regular harmless text I would prefer to keep
> - thing 3

becomes:

> - thing 1
> - thing 2
> - thing 3

---

Okay, I'm silly, I didn't know org-mode would collapse things. It does indeed say:

> - thing 1
> - thing 2...
> - thing 3

And S-TAB will hide/show all text. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very odd behaviour.  I use org-mode a lot and have never seen this problem.  Are you quite sure it doesn't become;

```
    * thing 1
    * thing 2...
    * thing 3
```

Comment: @rutger, try 'Shift-TAB' a few times to expand all of the entries. Or try placing the point on "thing 1", for example, and click TAB to expand

Comment: if it does become as mark says, place the point on * thing 2 and hit TAB to see your "plain" text again